# How can you access SVN over HTTP in a Windows environment?

Tags: windows, svn

What's the best practice for accessing SVN over HTTP in a Windows environment?

In Linux, we connect SVN to Apache all the time, so we can address remote repositories over HTTP.  Is there a way to connect SVN to IIS, or some equally handy way to let you access an SVN repo on a Windows machine over HTTP?

Comment: I mis-worded this question.  I was talking less about "Windows," and more about "IIS."  But the first answer is also about right -- you just need to install Apache.  In fact, Apache should almost be considered an intrinsic part of an SVN install.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apache happily runs on Windows

Answer (score 2):

If you're not looking forward to setting this up manually, download the free [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). Comes with a decent management console as well.

It runs based on Apache however, so if you want to run it on a machine that also runs IIS, you will have to use a non-default port, or assign a second IP address to that machine and tell IIS to only bind to the first IP.

To do the latter, check out [this page](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2008/09/02/prevent-iis-from-binding-to-all-assigned-ip-addresses.aspx), or any of the other decent tutorials on the web. This should work for IIS6 and up at least. Older versions were a little different.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I set up an svn/http/windows machine I set up an Apache server. Google provides [quite a few link suggestions on the topic](http://www.google.se/search?q=setting+up+svn+http+apache+windows).

Answer (score 1):

I have it running on my windows home server with apache

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exaclty what you asking about as you say access and then setup.

If you want to setup an SVN host/server, then your best bet as other have said is to setup Apache on Windows with the SVN module.

If you are wanting to checkout, update, commit then you are looking for an svn client. A great one is [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisevn.tigris.org) or you can also use the command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people have suggested installing Apache but that seems like a lot just to connect to an SVN server.  I think you'd be better off looking into SVN's command line client.